# Set data from Viewmodel to activity android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I am new to the `MVVM` architecture. I get data from db in my `viewmodel` and now I want to set that data to EditTexts in `activity`

```
    class EmployeeViewModel : BaseViewModel<EmployeeNavigator>() {

    var userList = ArrayList<EmployeeResponse>()
    var mName = MutableLiveData<EmployeeResponse>()


    fun fetchUsersAndSaveInDB(toString: String) {
        dialogMessage.value = "Fetching Data..."
        dialogVisibility.value = true
        mDisposable.add(DataProvider.fetchUsersAndSave(Consumer {
            getUsersFromDB()
        }, Consumer {
            checkError(it)
        }, toString))
    }

    private fun getUsersFromDB() {
        mDisposable.add(DataProvider.getUsersFromDb(Consumer {
            dialogVisibility.value = false
            userList = it as ArrayList<EmployeeResponse>
            mName.value = userList[0]
        }, Consumer { checkError(it) }))
    }

}
```

I got data in `mName` object now I want to set this data to edittexts in my `activity`. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Try to observe `mName` in your `Activity/Fragment` and update `EditText` when change in `mName`

Answer (score 4):

Here is more Kotlin way to do it.

Add this dependency to make observe function look shorter

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-rc03'
```

If you have only one functional parameter you don't need to pass it inside the curly brackets. 
So in `Activity` you can do next:

```
mViewModel.mName.observe(this) {
    it?.let { tv_emp_name.setText(it.empName) }
}
```

Also following [Kotlin style guidelines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide) it's better to use camelCase naming (Hungarian notation is allowed in this case) for layout IDs if you are using `kotlinx.android.synthetic`. You might also remove m prefix for variables.

Following all these your code would look like:

```
viewModel.name.observe(this) {
    it?.let { tvEmpName.setText(it.empName) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  mViewModel.mName.observe(this, Observer {
      if (it != null) {
          tv_emp_name.setText(it.empName)
      }
  })
```

Written this code in Activity and able to set data to EditText

Answer (score 2):

In Activity Do below three steps :

1.Declare your ViewModel in activity.

```
private lateinit var viewModel: EmployeeViewModel
```

2. Initialize your viewmodel :

   ```
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PostViewModel::class.java)
   ```
3. Observer your data from ViewModel :

   ```
    viewModel.getWhateverData()
            .observe(this,
                Observer<List<"Your class">> { userPost ->
                    adapter?.setPosts(userPost)
                    recycler_view.adapter = adapter
                })
   ```

Also in your viewmodel method you have not mentioned what exactly you want to observe.

Demo Of viewmodel

```
class PostViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: PostRepository = PostRepository()
    private var userId: Int = -1
    lateinit var userPost: LiveData<List<Post>>

    fun getUserPost(id: Int): LiveData<List<Post>> {
        this.userId = id
        userPost = repository.getUserPost(id)
        return userPost
}
}
```

Let me know if still any help required also so can look into below demo if needed.